# Gradle unable to find internal dependency

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

### Problem

I am developing an Android library. This library lives in a multi-module Gradle project with the following structure:

```
├── legacy
│   ├── src
│   │   └──...
│   └── build.gradle
├── data
│   ├── src
│   │   └──...
│   └── build.gradle
├── feature
│   ├── src
│   │   └──...
│   └── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

`data` depends on `legacy`.

```
// data/build.gradle
implementation project(":legacy")
```

`feature` depends on `data` and `legacy`.

```
// feature/build.gradle
implementation project(":legacy")
implementation project(":data")
```

`feature`, `data`, and `legacy` are all Android library modules. `feature` is the published Android library. `data` and `legacy` are not used outside this project, and are therefore not published anywhere.

My Android application depends on the published `feature` AAR artifact.

```
implementation "feature:<version>" // package omitted for obfuscation
```

Gradle has no problem finding the `feature` library. However, Gradle throws an error because it wants to find `data` and `legacy`.

```
Execution failed for task ':mobile-app:mergeDevDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':mobile-app:devDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find feature:data:unspecified.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - ... // omitted
     Required by:
         project :mobile-app > feature:<version>
```

I don't think it matters, but the `mobile-app` project is using a locking plugin, Nebula's [Gradle Dependency Lock Plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-dependency-lock-plugin).

---

### Attempted fixes

I'm a little confused why this error is happening at all. I expected the classes of `legacy` and `data` to be included in the `feature` AAR. That is clearly not the case. If that can be done, I prefer that solution.

Here are some dependency variations I've tried so far.

```
// feature/build.gradle

// doesn't work; same error
api project(":legacy")
api project(":data")

// doesn't work; mobile-app doesn't complain about missing artifacts, but fails to compile:
// cannot find symbol class <class in legacy>
compileOnly project(":legacy")
compileOnly project(":data")
```

I can successfully compile and run `mobile-app` if I use dependency substitution to replace the `feature` AAR with my local copy of the code repo.

```
// settings.gradle of mobile-app project
includeBuild('../feature') {    // this is the local relative path to the project
    dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('feature') using project(':feature')
    }
}
```

However, this is not an appropriate solution to publish and subsequently enforce upon the entire dev team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle modules map 1:1, more or less, with Java/Android libraries.

Adding a dependency (`implementation` or `api`) to a library does not cause that dependency to get compiled into the library. Otherwise you would get class path collisions if you depended on two libraries which themselves depended on the same library as each other.

Instead, adding a dependency to a library adds that dependency to the library's POM and/or gradle.module file, which gets published along with the JAR or AAR to the repository. Consumers of the library (i.e. other Gradle or Maven projects, like your app) then parse that POM, and thus know which additional dependencies to download.

The way I see it, your options are:

1. Publish `data` and `legacy` to a repository your app can consume, just like `feature`. Your app won't consume them directly, but they'll be there for Gradle to download when it sees that `feature` requires them.
2. Move the code from `data` and `legacy` inside of `feature` (and mark it all as Kotlin `internal` or Java package-private to prevent it from being public API).
3. Refactor `feature` to publicly define all of its data sources as interfaces. Move the `data` and `legacy` modules into your app project and refactor them to provide the necessary concrete implementations of `feature`'s required interfaces.